# Open specific software version from terminal

Tags: command-line

On my pc I have 2 versions of the same software (Blender 2.79 and 2.80) installed, and I need both of them. For debugging purposed I need to launch Blender 2.80 from terminal, so that I can see all the executed functions and the print() outputs, but when I type "blender" it opens the 2.79 version.

I probably need to add that I downloaded Blender 2.80 as a portable package (.zip file), because I didn't want to overwrite the 2.79 install.

How can I open Blender 2.80 from terminal?

### EDIT

As explained in the comments, it's possible to to run the 2.8 version by running the executable, but that would require typing the path every time, which is kind of a bummer.

A possible solution is a script, I guess, but is there a way to create a custom command in the terminal (like `blender2.80`), or any other way to open it with a short line?

Comment: You'll have to open them with paths, `whereis blender` can be used to find the `apt` installed one (2.79 I assume), the 2.80 you expanded from zip so you should already know where that one is.

Comment: Yes, I know where it is, but typing the 2.80 executable path every time is quite annoying... I updated the question with more info about my needs, thanks for the help

Comment: you can define an `alias` that includes the path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution (there are likely many).

Create a link and use a different command for the later version. Because I don't know where you have Blender 2.80 located (directory), I'll use the command `ls` as an example.

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:/de2900/lubuntu_64$   sudo ln -s /bin/ls /usr/local/bin/blah
```

In this example, I've created a link (soft) for the command `ls` and put it in `/usr/local/bin` calling it `blah`.  So when I type `blah` now, it'll run `ls`.

Replace `/bin/ls` with the location of your Blender 2.80 binary, and replace `blah` with whatever you think is appropriate (and ideally not used by something else, ie. `whereis blah` might be worthwhile to check the command isn't already used).

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:/de2900/lubuntu_64$   blah
bionic  eoan-desktop-amd64.iso         eoan-desktop-amd64.iso.zsync      kde_neon     qatracker.py   rcksum-Nkzfe5   zsync_eoan.sh
blah    eoan-desktop-amd64.iso.zs-old  eoan-desktop-amd64.iso.zsync.old  qa_query.py  rcksum-BvAetb  zsync_disco.sh
```

`/usr/local/bin/` could also be `~/bin/` if it's set up and in your $PATH.  It's a directory available for all users, so if you have other users on your system, they'll also be able to run it (if they have access to wherever it's located)

PS:  `alias` is possibly a better alternative.

Comment: I’d prefer a link to alias – it can work for all users and independently on the shell currently running.

Comment: It works flawlessly! Thanks very much man!

Comment: I prefer links too, why it was my answer.

Comment: @Melebius thanks for the suggestion! I have already set it up like @guiverc said, but if I have any problem I'll definetely give `alias` a shot